# Unable to use Concave representation of physics shape

Tags: ios, shapes, scenekit

Whenever I assign a Concave physics shape

```
let physicsShape = SCNPhysicsShape(node: starNode, options: [SCNPhysicsShapeTypeKey:SCNPhysicsShapeTypeConcavePolyhedron])
starNode.physicsBody = SCNPhysicsBody(type: SCNPhysicsBodyType.Dynamic, shape: physicsShape)
```

the starNode just falls through all other nodes. I created starNode in Blender. I also noticed that in Scene Editor I am unable to assign PhysicsShapeType of starNode to Concave. Why is this happening and how do I fix it? The Convex shape type is out of question because it is an inaccurate representation of geometry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/scenekit/scnphysicsshape/shapetype/1508890-concavepolyhedron):

> #### `SCNPhysicsShapeTypeConcavePolyhedron`
>
> The physics shape is a concave polyhedron closely following the surface of the geometry.
>
> This option provides the highest level of detail, at a high cost to simulation performance. Use it only for irregularly shaped bodies where precise collision behavior is crucial to your app’s design.
>
> This shape type may only be used for static physics bodies (that is, those whose `type` property is `SCNPhysicsBodyTypeStatic`).

If you need a dynamic shape to be concave, your best bet is to create a compound shape from multiple `SCNPhysicsShape` objects (or from an hierarchy of nodes and their geometry).

Comment: still crashing for me. type is .static